# Как связать два разных поля Input type radio без JS

Tags: input, radio

Есть два поля инпутов, можно ли сделать так чтобы при выборе пола "мужской" атоматически ставилось "молодой человек" в другом поле инпутов, и так же само  при выборе пола  "женский" ставилось "девушка" в другом поле. Можно ли это сделать без JS?

```
<p>
    Пол:
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="man">
    <label for="man">мужской</label> 
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="woman"> 
    <label for="woman">женский</label>   
</p>


<p>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" id="boy">
    <label for="boy">Молодой человек</label>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" id="girl">
    <label for="girl">Девушка</label>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

html и css не могут менять атрибуты самостоятельно.
можно сделать внешний вид такой, как-будто отмечается то, что нужно, но при отправке формы это работать не будет, всё равно скрипт нужен будет